# is fire alarm system conduit color clearly identified on NFPA or UFC?

Tags: fireplace, conduit

Inspector says that I have to use red emt conduit for fire alarm system. I want to prove that it doesn't specified in any standarts.

Comment: Have you checked NFPA 72 already?

Comment: http://www.firealarm.org/myth_buster.html

Answer (score 2):

The only marking I am aware of is the branch circuit circuit breaker is required to be identified with RED, and the location of the OCPD is to be permanently identified at the fire alarm control panel NEC 2014 760.41 & 760.121. NFPA 72 is referenced in the commentary for 760.41 with the same information and no colored conduit requirement.

Answer (score 1):

If you work on a government installation where there's a fire marshal who created his job out of nothing and will do anything to keep it (sound familiar?) You better bid on running red conduit, painting Greenfield, boxes, even extension rings when you drop speakers in a ceiling etc... Just saying....
Master Electrician
Nicet FASIII
30 years exp.
17 in govt intallations

Comment: This seems more like an annoyed rant than an answer. Maybe [edit] to remove the portion about the fire marshal. While it might be true, it detracts from what seems like it could be a good answer.